# Spring boot + cassandra

Tags: configuration, cassandra, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I started learning cassandra and I wanted to connect with Spring boot framework but I got a lot of errors an misunderstanding. First time I've spent whole day for understanding that I have to use Cassandra 2.x.x version not 3.x.x because Spring data Cassandra doesn't support it. So I delete any version in maven and it runs! The second time I did exactly like last time but I got some errors again, is it fortuna or what? I cannot understand anything! Please, clarify me somebody.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.libra</groupId>
    <artifactId>libra</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>libra</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Config Cassandra

```
package com.libra.configs;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories("com.libra.domain.repositories")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration{

    private static final String KEYSPACE_NAME = "libra";
    private static final String CONTACT_POINTS = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int PORT = 9042;

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {

        return KEYSPACE_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContactPoints() {
        return CONTACT_POINTS;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPort() {
        return PORT;
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations operations() throws Exception {

        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject(), new MappingCassandraConverter(new BasicCassandraMappingContext()));
    }
}
```

the table is:

```
package com.libra.domain;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

import java.util.UUID;

@Table
public class Book {

    @PrimaryKey
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    private String author;

    private int count;

    public Book(){

    }

    public Book(UUID id, String name, String author, int count){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

and I try to run from CommandLine:

```
package com.libra;

import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs;
import com.libra.domain.Book;
import com.libra.services.BookService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        bookService.saveBook(new Book(UUIDs.timeBased(),"name","author",3));

    }
}
```

the errors:

```
2016-04-02 22:51:39.897  INFO 5388 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-04-02 22:51:43.080 ERROR 5388 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.libra.LibraApplication.main(LibraApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraInvalidQueryException: unconfigured table book; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table book
    at org.springframework.cassandra.support.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:116) ~[spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cassandra.config.CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraCqlSessionFactoryBean.java:74) ~[spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.libra.services.BookService.saveBook(BookService.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.libra.LibraApplication.run(LibraApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table book
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:214) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate$12.doInSession(CqlTemplate.java:503) ~[spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate$12.doInSession(CqlTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:471) ~[spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:1209) ~[spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:642) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:237) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:232) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:59) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table book
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:102) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:149) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:183) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2300(RequestHandler.java:44) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:751) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:573) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1009) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:932) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254) ~[netty-handler-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:242) ~[netty-codec-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:847) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) ~[netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111) ~[netty-common-4.0.27.Final.jar:4.0.27.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_65]

2016-04-02 22:51:43.086  INFO 5388 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/Desktop/libra/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-cql/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-dse/2.1.9/cassandra-driver-dse-2.1.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.9/cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.0.27.Final/netty-handler-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.0.27.Final/netty-buffer-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.0.27.Final/netty-common-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.0.27.Final/netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.0.27.Final/netty-codec-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/3.0.2/metrics-core-3.0.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jersey/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jersey-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.om/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.6.5/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/LastBreath/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%2015.0.2/lib/idea_rt.jar]
2016-04-02 22:51:43.090  INFO 5388 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-04-02 22:51:43.090  INFO 5388 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6cc7b4de: startup date [Sat Apr 02 22:51:30 MSK 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-04-02 22:51:43.092  INFO 5388 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are two issues combined here.

1. Spring Data Cassandra needs to know the entities before it can create tables within Cassandra. This is done when creating the `Session`. 
   Spring scans for entities annotated with `@Persistent` or `@Table` and uses `com.libra.configs` as base package. This is, because `AbstractCassandraConfiguration.getEntityBasePackages` defaults to the package of the subclass, `CassandraConfig` in your case.
   Override `getEntityBasePackages` in `CassandraConfig` and return `com.libra.domain` so entities will be scanned from a different base package.

   ```
   public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

       // …

       @Override
       public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
           return new String[]{"com.libra.domain"};
       }

       // …
   }
   ```
2. Spring Boot supports Cassandra by configuring the application using  [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-cassandra), but it lacks the `SchemaAction` option. However, we have a [Github ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4886) to track this issue.

HTH, Mark